# Angular build error: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve index.ngfactory"

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

This error is happening when running `ng build --prod` or `ng build --aot`. It strangely only happens in our dev branch and not in the production branch. There are no differences between the package.json, tsconfig.json, or angular.json files between the two branches.

We have already tried:

- rebooting
- deleting node_modules and reinstalling
- copying node_modules from the working branch
- nuking the whole project and checking it out again
- running `npx npm-check-updates -u -f /^@progress/; npm i`

The only progress we are able to make is getting other nonsensical error messages.

Here is the error message.:

```
ERROR in <componentfile>.component.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grId/dist/es2015/index.ngfactory' in '<componentfolder>'
```

It looks like the issue may be that "kendo-angular-grId" has an inadvertent capitalization on the i, but in the file that's importing it, it's spelled normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed the capital I, but in a different file than I had initially looked at.